# lucene fuzzy query is not working in solr

Tags: java, mysql, solr

At present my application was using Lucene4 (lucene-core-4.0.0.jar) to index and search data. Below is one of the field I indexed in lucene. I have also added the data for the field.

```
source:cloud-based  
source:cloud control  
source:cloud sync  
source:cloud-up  
source:cloud-set  
source:cloud search
```

This is the lucene fuzzy query I am using to do the search.

```
    source:cloud~0.7
```

The same query is not finding any results in Solr4, I am not getting any idea what is wrong. I am using Standard Query Parser.

This is the field I added in schema.xml

```
<field name="source"      type="text_general"   indexed="true"  stored="true"       multiValued="false" />


 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Can you also suggest If it is a good idea to use Extended DisMax Query parser.